# ui-select error "Can't interpolate: {{$select.getPlaceholder()}}"

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

Here is the full error I get in angular ui-select

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{$select.getPlaceholder()}} TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

My markup is:

```
  <ui-select multiple ng-model="case.keywords" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select keywords...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="keywords in keywords | filter: $select.search">
      <div ng-bind-html="keyword.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
<p>Selected: {{case.keywords}}</p>
```

Nothing special in controller other than `get`ting the array of keywords from db. Obviously `ngSanitize` and `ui.select` are included in the module dependencies.

The other issue I have is that choices are not visible. I am able to show the selected ones, but list of choices is not visible. I am using bootstrap theme, `select.css` is referenced. Here's what it looks like

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select
this is the wiki of ui-select. It shows how `$select` is used. I simply took it from there

Comment: What version of angular and ui-select are you using?

Comment: can you tell how and when "Keywords" is set ? and also case.keywords ? .
im trying to understand the sequence.

also , is keywords list greater than Case.Keywords ? if yes , you should see choices when you click UISelect ( but these choices will not show selected items )

Comment: The version of ui-select is 0.9.6

Comment: @SunilVurity `keywords` is a scope variable  (array of objects) fetched from the database, I assign it in the controller. I use the Chrome add-on _ng-inspector for AngularJS_ to inspect the scope, it shows me that  `keywords` array is the keywords table in the database (which is what I want). `case.keywords` is where the ***selected*** choices are saved. For testing I initialize it to two keywords: aaa and bbb as seen in the image above, but on production it will be initially empty. Thanks

Comment: Most likely issue could be , uiselect is getting the list as undefined and it's running repeater on it and hence length not defined. Can you try setting Keywords =[] on load , I guess this should resolve the error you see

Comment: @Sincere And the angular version? The reason I ask is that I have put off migrating from ui-select2 even though it is deprecated b/c of some bugs in ui-select. I believe some multiple selections with the bootstrap theme did not work correctly prior to version 1.2.18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions from @SunilVurity and @Fiver gave me hints that lead me to resolve the issue:

**First** I changed `keywords`to `keyword` in:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="keywords in keywords | filter: $select.search">
```

**Second** in my controller I had:

```
appFactory.getKeywords().then(function (keywords){
  $scope.keywords = keywords;
  $scope.case = {};
  $scope.case.selectedKeywords = [];
});
```

Which I changed to:

```
$scope.case = {};
$scope.keywords = [];
learningCasesFactory.getKeywords().then(function (keywords){
  $scope.keywords = keywords;
  $scope.case.selectedKeywords = [];
});
```

As you can see in the controller, the `get` function is asynchronous which returns an undefined list to the view on load which caused the error I mentioned in the question. After updating the controller the error disappeared. This SO question helped [AngularJS Interpolation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432127/angularjs-interpolation-error).

**Third** the `uiselect` and `angular` versions can cause issues. My angular version is 1.2.9. This [ui-select Github issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/264) shows that upgrading the angular version solves the issue, I upgraded it to 1.3.11

Thanks @SunilVurity and @Fiver

Comment: Great !! Good to know I could help in someway